# How to substitute text across line breaks?

Tags: substitute, line-breaks

I would like to reformat code in an entire file from this brace style:

```
if (condition)
{
    body;
}
```

… into this brace style<sup>1</sup>:

```
if (condition) {
    body;
}
```

The bulk of the task should be accomplishable by relocating the opening braces.  I would like to do something like

```
:%s/^M *{$/ {/
```

… but substitutions don't seem to work across line breaks.

Is there a way to make substitutions work across line breaks?  If not, what is the next-best solution that does not involve an external command or plugin?  (I'm more interested in text-editing technique than in specialized programming tools.)

---

<sup>1</sup> No flame wars about the choice of brace style, please!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `\n` to do substitutions across multiple lines.  There are also special characters which start with `\_` that are the same as their normal counterparts, except it adds newline to their character class.  For instance, `\_s` is the same as `\s`, except it also matches newline characters.  Here is your search and replace statement with this special character:

```
:%s/\n *{$/ {/
```

Of course, you can make the regex more specific, since this one may match more than you want.

References:

- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines
- `:help \_`

Comment: I was just typing an answer ;-) Here's my solution: `:%s/)\n^\s*{$/) {/`, which also makes sure there's the preceding line ends with a `)`...

Comment: Yes of course.  The regex could be made safer, but I really was just demonstrating the special characters.   I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! It's kind of annoying that you're supposed to use `\n` to represent a line break in the regex, but `^M` (`Ctrl-V M`) to represent a line break in the substitution text. That's just how it is, I guess.